# How do I display grid content in Bootstrap Carousel?

Tags: bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am working with Bootstrap and EE 3.4.5 Grid and need a little help on the carousel.

With the following code all instances of the slide have class 'active'

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
  <!-- Indicators -->

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>


  <div class="carousel-inner">
    {slider}
    <div class="item {if count == 1}active{/if}"> <img src="{slider:photo}" style="width:100%" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>{slider:title}</h1>
          <p>{slider:sub_title}</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="{slider:links_to}" role="button">{slider:button_text}</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {/slider}
 </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
```

If I remove {if count == 1}active{/if} the carousel disappears, but I only need active on the first slide. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that because it is in a grid it requires the following:

```
{if slider:count == 1}active{/if}
```